# Component methods do not fire in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3

Using Laravel 5.3, I have the following in `/resources/assets/js/app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('./components/test-component'); // custom

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

The component `test-component.js` is simply

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
    data() {
        return {
            someData: '' // does work!
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('ready'); // does not fire...
    },
    methods: {
        testMethod() {
            console.log('here'); // does not fire...
        }
    }
});
```

Then in a Blade template,

```
<test-component>
    <form>
        <!-- a bunch of HTML markup here... -->
        <button type="button" @click="testMethod">Fire a test method...</button>
    </form>
</test-component>
```

When a button is clicked, nothing shows in the console. Moreover, `mounted` does not fire when the form is loaded. At the same time, `someData` model binding works perfectly!

#### Question

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: try putting `<test-component inline-template>` instead of just `<test-component>`

Comment: @kishanterry Perfect, this is the right answer. `template` is not even necessary.

Comment: glad it helped. But Single File Components are much better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add template to component options:

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
   template: ` <form>
    <!-- a bunch of HTML markup here... -->
    <button type="button" @click="testMethod">Fire a test method...</button>
</form>`,
  //..

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a template:

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
    data() {
        return {
            someData: '' // does work!
        };
    },
    template: '<div></div>', // add your template here
    mounted() {
        console.log('ready'); // does not fire...
    },
    methods: {
        testMethod() {
            console.log('here'); // does not fire...
        }
    }
});
```